# Flash linking to external file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Here is the script am using to open an external html file from moviclip but it is opening in new tab. How to make it open in the same window?

```
function ShowDesignerhome(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("77.html");
  navigateToURL(targetURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"_self"` as the second argument for your call to `navigateToURL()`. More information:

```
navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self");
```

> Parameters
>
> `request:URLRequest`
>
> `window:String (default = null)` — The browser window or HTML frame in
>   which to display the document indicated by the request parameter. You
>   can enter the name of a specific window or use one of the following
>   values:
> `"_self"` specifies the current frame in the current window.
>   `"_blank"` specifies a new window.
> `"_parent"` specifies the parent of the
>   current frame.
> `"_top"` specifies the top-level frame in the current
>   window.

*PS. Please make use of the "accept" button next to answers (this goes for answers on your current questions).*

Comment: Thanks!! am done..:) One more thing, Is it possible to link to particular movieclip from html file. My site home page is flash when i go to some externals html files, i have a link back to home page(swf file) but the problem is the flash loads from the loading page & introduction part. I need to skip the introduction when i come from the html files. Is it possible??? I am planning to create 2 swf files, one with introduction another without introduction which has to be linked from html page. but i think it is the blind way so if u have any better idea please suggest. Thank you!!

Comment: @Sowmya Your question can be answered by reading about [FlashVars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a second parameter to your navigateToURL call

```
navigateToURL(targetURL, "_self");
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()